# android layouts overlapping with changing sizes

Tags: android, layout

I have a problem with a specific layout in Android.

What I want to achieve is approximately this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QYh1.jpg

- The green area should always be visible at the bottom of the screen (size can change, but only marginally)
- The red area should fill the rest of the screen on top.
- The cyan area (inside the red layout) is a ScrollView and can change size and should not grow bigger than the space available

What happens is this: when the list expands, depending on the layout (i have tried linear, relative, mix of those,...), either the red or green area is overlapped with the other and is not accessible any more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFPmY.jpg

I have tried this for a day now and whatever I do, some part of the layout is always overlapped. Is there a way to tell a ScrollView to only expand to a certain height? I know maxHeight doesn't exist. I highly appreciate every input as this is driving me crazy now! Is this possible at all with Android?

Comment: If the list is very small and there is space between the list + button how should the green area behave?

Comment: the red area should take all the space above the green area, even if it is not as tall. and the red area should also resize the ScrollView accordingly if it becomes too tall